# select query of sphinxql returns everything in string irrespective of data type in table

Tags: php, full-text-search

I wrote my config file as attribute as -:

```
sql_attr_float  = rad_latitude
sql_attr_float  = rad_longitude
```

**but on a select query i get the data as**

```
 array(2) {
 ["rad_latitude"]=>
 string(9) "-0.371600" //this needs to be float
 ["rad_longitude"]=>
 string(9) "-0.878434"  //this needs to be float
 }
```

it comes out as a string and i cant calculate geodist as it's in string.

Answer (score 0):

sphinxql's execute function returns the data in string but you can use it in geodist query as it is. just remember not to use quotes on the columns name in your query, if you put quotes over it sphinx treats it as a string and i wont produce any result.